# Localization text direction supportsrtl:false in arabic in android for string resources not working

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-resources

I am trying to localize my app in arabic by using **

> android:supportsRtl:false

** in my `manifest` file.It actually works for all the strings declared in the `xml` layout i.e **

> android:text="@string/done_btn"

**and all the arabic localized strings are written ltr(left  to Right) but those strings which are written programmatically using resources strings i.e

> getString(R.id.name)

are localized but it is using it's default written type i.e rtl(Right to left) instead of ltr(left to Right) thereby destroying the layout and design of the page.
**N.B:1>   i already tried setting `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` or `android:textDirection="ltr"` to the `textview` with localized string or the container layout which it holds.**
Any help would be highly appreciated.